# D3js: "How to append distinct paths for distinct values?"

Tags: d3.js, path, append, pentaho

I´ve got a dataset of rows:

```
-------------------------------------
service | timestamp           | value
-------------------------------------
4       | 2019-01-15 xx:xx:xx | 14
-------------------------------------
4       | 2019-01-15 xx:xx:xx | 14  
-------------------------------------
8       | 2019-01-15 xx:xx:xx | 18  
-------------------------------------
8       | 2019-01-15 xx:xx:xx | 18 
-------------------------------------
etc.
```

Now I want to "draw" single lines for the service 4 and 8.

I´ve included a filter:

```
var servData = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.service == 4
});

...

svg.append("path")
 .datum(servData) 
 .attr("class", "line") 
 .attr("d", line);
```

This works if I write a filter and append for every unique service,
but I want to append the services dynamiclly.

For example:
Service has 2 to 5 different values

Append 2 to 5 "Paths" for every unique service number.

How can I append the paths to the svg graphic

without appending every service hardcoded?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [general update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218)

```
var paths = svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(pathsData)

var pathsEnter = paths.enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr("class", "line") 
  .attr('d', line)
```

---

## Edit

Based on the pic you've shared in the comments

- calculate a unique array of all the `service` values. (in your example it would be `[4, 8]` but it would be data-driven.)
- Then use that array as the data for a group of `service lines`.
- Position each line according to your yScale.
- Bonus: create a color scale to dynamically determine the stroke color of the line based on its value within the service values array.

```js
const data = [{service: 4, otherData: '...'},{service: 4, otherData: '...'},{service: 8, otherData: '...'},{service: 8, otherData: '...'},{service: 12, otherData: '...'},{service: 12, otherData: '...'}
]

// Get a unique array from data
const serviceData = Array.from(new Set(data.map(a => a.service)));

// create a color scale if you need
const color = d3.scaleLinear().domain(serviceData).interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl).range([d3.rgb("#ff0000"), d3.rgb('#257c00')]);

const width = 500;
const height = 300;
const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height)

// Bind to data
const lines = svg.append('g').attr("class", "service-lines-group").selectAll('line')
  .data(serviceData)

// Enter selection - create lines for each data point
const linesEnter = lines.enter()
  .append('line')
  .attr("class", "service-line")
  .attr('x1', 0)
  .attr('x2', width)
  .attr('y1', d => d * 10)
  .attr('y2', d => d * 10)
  .attr('stroke', (d, i) => {
    return color(d)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hm that doesnt seem to do the trick, i want to "render" a seperat line for every distinct service number. This seems to join them?

Comment: Do you have a sketch (or annotated screenshot) of how you want this to look?

Comment: [Picture](https://imgur.com/a/u9ejRrB) this is how it should look like. Two seperat lines for two service numbers, there are multiple service numbers in my dataset and I dont want to "filter" them hardcoded like I do now.

Comment: Ok thanks for the pic. Based on that I've expanded on how I would solve your particular problem.

Comment: Thank you, it would be enough to append paths based on the array of the dataset. Can I do that with array.from? So kinda filter the data for each distinct service and draw a path based on the value data.

Comment: The above code does exactly what you are describing.